# apt broken by "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By" (tor related)

Tags: ubuntu, apt, tor

I was trying to remove, then reinstall, **tor** browser.
**apt** is now no longer working;

*sudo apt update*

> E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/ focal: /usr/share/keyrings/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg != /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg
> E: The list of sources could not be read.

I tried removing
/usr/share/keyrings/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg
and
/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg
to **no** effect..

Comment: How exactly did you try to remove then reinstall? Asking because the repository is correct so just uninstalling the package and reinstalling (or just reinstalling in one go with the `--reinstall` parameter) should be trivial.

Comment: As i remember I did   "apt purge tor", later apt install tor I did ;. Create a new file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ named tor.list. Add the following entries:

   deb     [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION> main
   deb-src [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg] https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org <DISTRIBUTION> main                  then added the gpg key as per https://support.torproject.org/apt/tor-deb-repo/

Comment: Please replace <DISTRIBUTION> with _focal_ in previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

My problems were caused by a change in the tor installation procedure.
Apt functionality was restored by deleting the tor file from */etc/apt/sources.list*.

Comment: Welcome to U&L. Maybe you could [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/736338/edit) the answer to expand it? It'd be good to explain the root cause and your solution in more detail. This way the answer can be helpful also in the future; others facing the same issue can follow your steps to get it resolved. [How do I write a good answer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) in the Help gives good pointers.

Comment: Please edit your answer to contain SPECIFIC info.

Comment: Vlastimil, What do you miss?